# auto logout after some time of inactivity

Tags: javascript

This is may be little confused ill try best to explain. I made a php website where a user gets logout if he is inactive/idle for 5 minutes. I have done this using JavaScript, I will provide code also. Now the main problem is suppose I have two pages "one.php" , "two.php" and both the pages are using same JavaScript code to logout. Now suppose I have opened both the pages in two different tabs of the browser and let say I am working on one.php, But After 5 minutes because my two.php was inactive I will be logout even if I am working on one.php. SO help me guys how to prevent this. don't get confuses with the very first line of code, I checked 15 seconds of inactivity but in comments it says 10 minutes

```
    var IDLE_TIMEOUT = (1/4) * 60;  // 10 minutes of inactivity
    var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    document.onclick = function() {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };
    document.onmousemove = function() {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };
    document.onkeypress = function() {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };
    window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);
    function CheckIdleTime() {
        _idleSecondsCounter++;
        console.log(_idleSecondsCounter);
        var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
        if (oPanel)
            oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
        if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
            // destroy the session in logout.php 
            document.body.addEventListener('click', logt, true); 
        }
    }

function logt()
{
    window.open('logout.php' , '_SELF');
}
```

Comment: Why don't you manage session on server side ?

Comment: Make the session (or whatever login mechanism you're using) last n minutes only.

Comment: Every tab of the browser will execute its own javascript code which will be independent of other tabs, so it will be best to maintain the time of your session on the server and every time you do an activity , set it to 0.

Comment: Can You guys explain your solutions@shubham and @bambam

Comment: Imposible without knowing your server side code

Comment: do you have any code snippet for this@ShyamTayal

Comment: <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root' , '' , 'secure_login');
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['uname']))
{
header('location:login.php');}
session_regenerate_id( true );
echo "Welcome = ".$_SESSION['uname'];
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="login_time.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 </body>
</html> this is what I am doing on server@bambam

Comment: I am doing Nothing special on server just trying to logout after some time properly. And I am facing this java-script problem@bambam

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0):

My idea: when user is active save timestamp in localstorage e.g. `'lastActivityAt': '2019-05-21T13:37:12'`. And using JS `setInterval` run periodicaly other procedure which check key `lastActivityAt` every 1-5min (and logout if no activity for 5 min). Localstorage is shared between all tabs so if you make action in one tab, then other tab will detect it

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider to manage your session on the server side. Meaning that requests to the server will reset a countdown there. So when a request is made after the user is logged out the server will check the expired countdown and send a proper response.

If you really want to handle this on the client side you can have a look at the [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) which allows you to store and access data across multiple tabs/windows as long as they are for the same domain.